# Biographical record...? What is it

Tags: terminology

"give a solid overall biographical record of your subject based on the book you have read.  Be sure to include a brief synopsis of all of the high and low points and successes and failures of your subject."

This my assignment, fro writing about a person of my choice. I've realized I don't exactly what a biographical record is. Google wasn't much help for a solid answer either. Can some one explain?

Comment: Did the biography assignment really recall humans as *subjects*?

Comment: Uh yea, I guess so. Is a bit odd.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the terminology of an academic (or non-academic) discipline and not about academia itself. It **may** be on-topic on [ell.se], [english.se] or [writers.se], but very likely the only person who can satisfyingly answer this is whoever made the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, a biography describes a course of a person's life. By a *solid overall biographical record*, I suppose you are instructed to include all phases of concerned person's history -- from childhood to current time or death (whichever is earlier) in detail.